Is Charging High Fees for Hajj Guidance by a Muallim Permissible in Islam?
Can anyone provide insights into the following statement regarding Islamic teachings?
Statement:
Taking a tax, extra fee, or charge from pilgrims intending to perform the obligatory duty of Hajj is impermissible.
Narrated by Ad-Diyaa with sahih isnaad.

In my country, and possibly across the Indian subcontinent, it's common for an "Alim" to accompany pilgrims. This individual, known as a Muallim, helps ensure the pilgrimage is performed correctly by finding mistakes and assisting throughout the process. However, they often charge significantly more than the usual cost.
For example, a Muallim might charge an additional 100,000 BDT per person on top of the usual cost, making the total for a married couple approximately 1.4 to 1.5 million BDT, which is extremely high.
My question is: Is this practice halal in Islam? Is it permissible to earn money in this way, which might seem exploitative or fraudulent?
